# select from final table(update table) concurrent select i.e select from two threads

Tags: select, concurrency, db2

Due to a concurrency issue in my project which happend due to 2 threads coming in together to do a select at same time, both recieve the same values which ideally should not happen.
After selecting a value it should perform a update and then second thread should select the updated value.
**Am using DB2**
 I thought of using this approach of using

> select number from final table(update tablename set columnanme=""
>   where )

.
My question is would this approach lock the db when the other thread comes in to select the value as theere is an update within select? and solve my concurrency issue.
OR
I was browsing and found another approach

> update table (.....) select col from table where  wait for
>   outcome

Would this select wait until the first thread finishes the select?

Comment: Per my understanding an update statement will lock the record until a COMMIT is performed. your SELECT statements may not gain exclusive control of the record and hence the issue I guess. You may try to use your select WITH CS and I think it should wait then

Comment: I think we need to know more about what your application is doing.  @PK20 is possibly right that upping the isolation level might fix this (although you might need RS, and _both_ statements have to be run in transactions)., but my intuition is twitching.  So, can we get at least both complete statements (anonymized if necessary)?

Comment: What do you want the reading thread to do? Block? Fail? Read the previous value?

Comment: I am using IBM DB2 9.7.

Comment: I am using this DB2 thru WMB (using ESQL). This connects to DB2 which has a table with columns seq_num, and 2 other columns which are used in where condition. The threads access this seq_num based on other two columns and then update the seq_num by incrementing so that the each of the accessing threads get unique seq_num. Thanks for solutions. @PK20 i shall implement with RS and see what happens.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse - I quite did not understand what you meant by twitching?

Comment: I happend to read that select uses share lock and isolation level tells howong the lock is held. Does it mean that share lock would allow multiple selects on the same row at same time?

Comment: @SpringLake - twitching, as in, I was suspecting you're doing something wrong.  Your suspicion in your last comment is correct - you are getting (at minimum) multiple reads of the same value.  You will need to completely serialize access to a row for this sort of scheme to work (highest isolation level).  However, the need for this is rare - it's usually better to just use a regular autogen column for db sequence keys.  What business reason are you generating keys this way for?

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse- Sorry for the delayed chat. I just need this as this value is to be passed to the back end (AS400) and they create dynamic queues based on the this unique id.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can certainly do to avoid multiple reads of the same value before it gets updated by one of the readers:

1. LOCK TABLE tablename IN EXCLUSIVE MODE;
2. SELECT id, ... FROM tablename WHERE ...;
3. UPDATE tablename SET id=newval WHERE ...;
4. COMMIT;

This will of course block the *full* table, which is maybe not what you want!

Alternative approach (relatively standard, but somewhat more involved programming logic):

1. SELECT id, ... FROM tablename WHERE ...
2. SELECT count(1) FROM FINAL TABLE (UPDATE tablename SET id=newval
   WHERE ... AND id=newval);
3. while this count(1) is zero (meaning: someone else meanwhile updated
   it)    repeat from 1)

--
Peter Vanroose,
       ABIS Training & Consulting,
       Leuven, Belgium.